# Java script error occured in the main process --Discord

Tags: apt, java

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. When I tried to run Discord it pops up an update. I downloaded the deb file however when I tried to install and run there is a javascript error.

A Javascript error occured in the main process
Uncaught exception:
Error:net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.(electron/js2c/browser_init.js:105:7068)
at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.emit(events.js:315:20)
at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.EventEmitter.emit(domain.js:467:12)

I tried installing from snap but still get the same error
My system is updated and upgraded.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error.
I deleted the `node_modules` folder in the root directory, after that I did
`npm install` and launched the discord.